# Fancybox gallery repeating images

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, image-gallery

I made a fancybox gallery and it works fine with images number but it shows the same image

e.g. if I have 5 images I can click next 4 times but the same image is shown unless I opened another image it will work on two images and so on

I used some random number to avoid caching but watching the firebug there is no errors and no request sent to get the new image

Here is my code

```
<a href="path/to/image/1/?cashe='+Math.random()+'" class="aGalleryHolder" rel="galleryGroup" ><img src="path/to/image/1/" class="galleryItems2" /></a>
```

and the JS tried with two different selectors and the same result

```
jQuery("a.aGalleryHolder").fancybox();
jQuery("a[rel=galleryGroup]").fancybox();
```

any ideas ?

http://jsfiddle.net/5VZ6h/1/

Here is the src it driving me crazy

Comment: i think the given url is incorrect try it like this :<a href="path/to/image/1?cashe='+Math.random()+'"

Comment: @Sora sorry but I removed the original path I forgot this the link is right do u have any other ideas

Comment: can u please provide me some of your code ?

Comment: maybe the Math.random value is saved the same in the fancybox and for that reason it gives you the same image again and again

Comment: @Sora forget about the Math.random it returns the same image over and over unless I open it it's not sending new request

Comment: you folder with the name '1' how are the images named in it maybe the images name is different the Math.random value

Comment: its just routing its not folder

Comment: try it like this <a href="path/to/image/1/?cashe='+Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1); +'" class="aGalleryHolder" rel="galleryGroup" ><img src="path/to/image/1/" class="galleryItems2" /></a>
this gives u a number between 1 to 10 than rename your images ex:1.png,2.png and try

Comment: see the link on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bad idea to mess with the original fancybox js file, unless you know what you are doing. Your fiddle shows changes from the original file, specifically from the line 792 and on.

From the original [fancybox js file at fancybox.net](http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js) 
Line 792 says :

```
$(this)
 .data('fancybox', $.extend({}, options, ($.metadata ? $(this).metadata() : {})))
 .unbind('click.fb')
 .bind('click.fb', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ...etc
```

Your edits http://jsfiddle.net/5VZ6h/1/ :

```
$(this)
 .die('click.fb')
 .live('click.fb', function(e) {       
  $(this).data('fancybox', $.extend({}, options, ($.metadata ? $(this).metadata() : {})))
  e.preventDefault();
  ... etc
```

As soon as I forked your fiddle with the original fancybox js code, it works properly. See it yourself : http://jsfiddle.net/jMWFp/3/

Comment: Thank you very much I am here to post the answer 
I figured it out , but I will accept your answer since it the right one and you are here to help me